# Slick withSession inserts into multiple tables test

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Have two tables say `Employees` and `Department`

have a test fixture, `sessionWrapper`,  which wraps each test. `sessionWrapper` is a simple fuunction which creates a new `session` and rolls back, in a `finally` block, after test completes running. again tests aren't meant to poluate database and best thing we decied is to rollback data. this is achieved by a simple `test` fixture, `sessionWrapper` which wraps each test as shown below. fixture provides `session`(that it created) to each test.

Now I have a test which inserts a `Employee` record into `Employees` table. `Employees` table has FK relatinship with `department` table. so I need to first `insert` `Department` record part of this test.

```
sessionWrapper { implicit session =>
  session.withTransaction {
    val departmentRow = DepartmentRow(1, Option("Department1"))
    val deptId = department.insert(departmentRow)

    val employeeRow = EmployeeRow(-1, Option(deptId), "John", "Doe")

    employee.insert(employeeRow)
  }
}
```

Throws

```
(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR: insert or update on table "employees" violates foreign key constraint "fk_employees_department"
 Detail: Key (dept_id)=(1) is not present in table "department".)
```

shouldn't `departmentRow` insert be seen by `employee` insert in a same transaction?

this is a fairly common scenario so how do you generally test such a simple FK relation use case?

Comment: Are you sure that you enter the department key correctly? How is the FK relationship described?

Comment: @Ashalynd : I updated question by appropriately adding `deptId` in `EmployessRow`. My FK relationship looks fine to me. do you see any issue? CREATE TABLE employees
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  dept_id integer,
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT employees_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_employees_department FOREIGN KEY (dept_id)
      REFERENCES department (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

Comment: Did you find solution? Was anything wrong in your definition of FK? ATM I'm facing the same issue and I have no idea what is wrong.