# Slick and play controller testing

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

have a play controller method

```
def insertDepartment = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  MyDataSourceProvider.db.withSession{ implicit session =>
    val departmentRow = DepartmentRow(1, Option("Department1"))
    departmentService.insert(departmentRow)
  }
}
```

note `MyDataSourceProvider.db` is providing `slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Database` and creating a `withSession` provides an `implicit` `session` to `departmentService.insert`

when I test `departmentService` `session` is provided by a text fixture as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810910/slick-withsession-inserts-into-multiple-tables-test). `sessionWrapper` is a simple function which creates a `session`, provides that `session` to a test block and rolls back data after test finishes.

```
sessionWrapper { implicit session =>

    val departmentRow = DepartmentRow(1, Option("Department1"))
    departmentService.insert(departmentRow)
}
```

This works nicely and as expected by not polluting database when `service` tests run. tests should not persist anything in the db but rollback after executing successfully.

now when testing `play` `controller` need a way to use `sessionWrapper`. to be able to roll back controller tests in a similar fashion to `service` tests.

note `MyDataSourceProvider.db.withSession` in `controller insertDepartment`.

wrapping `controller` **test** with `sessionWrapper` has no significance since controller `def` isn't accepting any `implicit session` but using one from `MyDataSourceProvider.db.withSession`

what's the best way to handle this? tried creating a `trait` controller, to be able to `inject` impl for a `trait` so mixin can be different for a test and real code but haven't found a  way to "pass" `session` for test and **not** for production code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since Slick is blocking, you don't need `Action.async`. I wonder why that even compiles, because I don't see a future there, but I am not that familiar with Play.

There are several alternatives for what you can do:

1. My favorite: not use transaction rollback for testing, but use a test database, which you re-create for each test.
2. pull out

   ```
   val departmentRow = DepartmentRow(1, Option("Department1"))
       departmentService.insert(departmentRow)
   ```

   into a method and only test that method, not the controller
3. use sessionWrapper in the controller and let it check for a configuration flag, that tells it if it is in test mode and should do a rollback, or if it is in production mode.